# LWC Pre-populate default values during record creation

Tags: lightning-web-components, create-records, default-value

I am trying to Pre-Populate some of the values during the record creation using `NavigationMixin` I am using below code

```
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__objectPage',
            attributes: {
                objectApiName: 'Request__c',
                actionName: 'new'
            },
            state: {
                 defaultFieldValues: defaultValues,
            }
        });
```

When I use static values for the defaultValues like below

```
const defaultValues = encodeDefaultFieldValues({
            "Account__c": "0014A01112K3Xl7",
            "Name": "Test CR45",
            "Account_Legal_Name__c": "Test Legal Account",
            "Priority__c": "Review"
        });
```

then these default values are set during the record creation. However, if I assign an object after stringify , it doesn't work , like below

```
const obj = {
            "Account__c": "0014A01112K3Xl7",
            "Name": "Test CR45",
            "Account_Legal_Name__c": "Test Legal Account",
            "Priority__c": "Review"
            } 

   let crDefValues =  JSON.stringify(obj);
        const defaultValues  = encodeDefaultFieldValues({
            crDefValues
        });
```

Does anyone if we set the defaultValues from the object like above? If not , what are other options to populate default values during the record recreation dynamically?

Comment: Why do you want to stringify? Would it not just work if you did `encodeDefaultFieldValues(obj)` in the second example?

Comment: Without stringify , it gives me error - [The value of a defaultFieldValues entry must be a string, boolean or number. Invalid value type for 'obj' is object.]

Comment: @PhilW- Actually, encodeDefaultFieldValues(obj) worked. Thanks. I have been trying encodeDefaultFieldValues({obj}) and it was giving me above error.